# Heatsinks next to CPU socket?

Tags: motherboard, heatsink

While researching the motherboards market, I've noticed that some have what seem like passive heatsinks to the top and left of the CPU socket (sometimes only on the top or on the left). For an example, see the design for Gigabyte's H170-Gaming 3.

Excluding assumptions, my question is: what are these parts, and what is their purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're usually heatsinks for the voltage regulator modules (VRM) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator_module

A VRM lowers the voltage from +12V supply rail to whatever the CPU needs, typically around 0.5-1.5v.

As mentioned in the comments the southbridge and northbridge can also covered by a heatsink. These are however usually below the CPU socket and further away. Depending on the motherboard and the chips used a heatsink may be required or it could just be added for visual effect.

Most modern CPU's no longer have a seperate northbridge, this is now completely integrated in the CPU die, here's an example diagram where items 3(b,c) are the CPU VRMs and item 8 is the southbridge/IOH/PCH heatsink:

[image]

Comment: Northbridge and/or southbridge may also require heatsinks.

Comment: yeah, if it's a tiny heat sink, more likely to be a VRM. If it's a larger passive heatsink, it's likely the northbridge

Comment: @Blaine I feel the OP's question was pretty general.

Comment: Ah you guys are right of course, let me add that in.

Comment: @ClassStacker: That is completely wrong. Modern CPUs are **always** powered by VRMs supplied off the 12v rail. There's a reason there's a 12v only CPU connector on modern boards, similarly there's a reason even 500w PSUs do not supply enough power on 5v or 3.3v to power a processor. 20-50 amps over long cables using 3.3v and 5v is what would really be unreasonable. CPUs have not been powered off the 3.3v rail since Pentium III's.

Comment: Ah, so thats the component that caught on fire on my Gigabyte H170 motherboard last night. Not sure how that happenned, maybe the heatsink detached for mthe components, but there was a lot of smoke and a bad smell